# appending to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /bin/bash for GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

I want to append a particular directory to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH from makefile. This i what i have done, but it doesn't work :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(shell pwd)/include/libraries/:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH";
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./test_udp.out
```

I am using bash shell in GNU/Linux. Now i get the following error

```
./test_udp.out: error while loading shared libraries: libuv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But when i modify it to

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/Device-Connectivity/Signaling/include/libraries/ ;  ./test_udp.out
```

It works.

Comment: try this..`LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(shell pwd)/include/libraries/:$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH";`

Comment: There's a problem when the path is initially empty and adding to it results in 
 a trailing `:`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/9906/196639

Answer (score -1):

Replace

> **"**$LD_LIBRARY_PATH **"**

with

> $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

It will work.